# SEO Advice Needed! Can you use a snippet from a big article as a new small article?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I'm quite new to SEO, I have a website that focuses on things to do in a city.

We have lots of articles like Top 10 / 20 restaurants etc.

We just opened a new section which uses Google Maps and has map points for all the individual things to do in the city. I would like to use snippets of text from the larger articles and create new articles with them.

For example: I would like to take the text for each of the restaurants on the Top 10 article and create 10 new articles with those pieces of text and link each one to a point on the map. The titles and URLs will all be unique and the focused keywords will be different too.

I'm also going to be linking to the big Top 10 article from each of these small article pages too.

I'm worried about it being seen as duplicate content by Google and would like some advice on best practices.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to worry about using information that you may not have permission to use. If you have all the rights sorted out, then you can use it.

About specifics of being seen as duplicate, well, it is, you haven't mention anything about rewriting the content.

Still, if your site offers enough new content and provide links to the sources of the texts that you are using, there should be no penalties or problems.

If, for instance, you use snippets, to give users and idea, and you link to the sites that offer the original information and the restaurant itself, then it's almost sure that not problem whatsoever should happen.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer, sorry if my post was a bit vague, this is all my content on my site, so it's all internal and nothing external is being linked to etc. I thought about paraphrasing, but we are talking about 500 individual venues that have been written about amongst loads of Top 10 articles. So the idea is to simply open up this new map section but use snippets of text from the bigger articles to promote the restaurants individually rather than them being combined into a large top 10 article.

Comment: As i understand your comment, all the content is yours, including main articles, so that part is covered. Then the rest of the answer applies, you won't be considered as duplicate or plagiarizing.

Answer (score 1):

The pages that you want to create is something like tag - archive pages. For example you have a tag page with the term blue and you list all the hotels with the term blue, or you create an aggregated page for the term blue

This technique is good but it should be used wisely. For example if you have 1000 hotel pages and you create 10 - 20 even 100  new pages that combine content from these 1000 pages it is perfectly good and it will rank without any problems and no penalty will happen. From  my experience these pages tend to rank higher

But if you have 1000 unique pages and create 10000 aggregated pages then your website may be penalized